# Get FaceBook Group Join Requests

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have explored Facebook Graph API explorer where I can get information regarding Users , pages and groups.

I find many things to get from graph API, but I didn't find field to get Member requests.

What I need to get details about join requests and answers of questions I asked from them before joining.

I can get these data by using scraping tool but I need to get the data using API.

Could you please let me know the way I can get the details from API or have button on group that can let me export?

Comment: scraping is not allowed, and afaik there is no api for this, so there is no way.

Comment: @luschn can I modify Facebook API or suggest them to allow me to get data

Comment: modify the api? how? that would be weird, it´s facebooks api, not yours...and suggest...well, i don´t think  they would just add something just because one developer wants it, to be honest. but you can try adding a bug report and see where it goes, maybe some other devs would subscribe to it ;)

Comment: they should make it open source

Comment: a lot of devs would make bad things with it then ;) (they did already, that´s why a lot of stuff does not work anymore nowadays)

Comment: just allow it log in user and user can be only get their own group data not others

Comment: You haven't read the news at all lately right? I would recommend reading about Cambridge Analytica. They did just what you said. They only access stuff that the user could access. People got angry and Facebook locked down what you now can access